# Check if there are changes in DBContext and Generate update script on the pot instead of using Package Manager Console

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, code-first

I would like to check see whether is there any change in DbContext and generate update script right on the pot instead of using Package Manager Console(`update-database -script -force -verbose -startupproject myproject`).

Any solution would be appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can archive it with help of `DbMigrator` and `MigratorScriptingDecorator`:

```
var configuration = new Configuration();
var migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);
//if you want to update database to latest migration
migrator.Update();

//if you want to get above update script without applying it to database
var scriptor = new MigratorScriptingDecorator(migrator);
var script = scriptor.ScriptUpdate(sourceMigration: null, targetMigration: null);
```

Comment: Hi @Slava Utesinov, thanks a lots for pointing out. I'll try this out and get back to u later.